# What does "in" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

I feel sometimes "in" seems to be used in the same way as "during", but it's hard to know if that's exactly the case, because the complement is not an event per se.

For example:

> Michael collapsed in a shrill cry.
>
> The building collapsed in an explosion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Michael collapsed in a shrill cry.

I think *in* here is kind of like *during*, because maybe he collapsed while making the sound, but also something like *into*- like at the end of Michael’s collapsing he let out a shrill cry. Also see the expression [collapse in(to) a heap](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/collapse+in+a+heap)

> The building collapsed in an explosion.

I think *in* is used like *during* here. During an explosion, the building collapsed.

Comment: In the first example, you could also think of in as after, which would be the most likely possibility. _Michael collapsed after a shrill cry._

Comment: Is "after" one of the possible definition of "in"?

Comment: Woken- yes. Prepositions in English are weird and can mean different things in different contexts. *in* can mean *during* or *after* or any number of things. @Artemis Hunter’s answer makes sense. Kind of the opposite of my interpretation - the collapsing may have come after the cry. I thought it happened before. Probably this all would happen so fast (collapsing tends to be fast) that it would be hard to tell what came first.

Comment: @Mixolydian You have a valid point. Usually though, collapsing would come after the cry. :P English _is_ a funny language.